# Compile and add an object file from a binary with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, ld

I am writing an Excel file builder in C++.

I have everything I need working, but I still rely on an external empty .xlsx file which I unzip, iterate through, and add data too as needed to create the final file.

I want to remove this dependency by turning the .xlsx file into a binary blob in the .rodata section of my executable, by turning it first into an object file like so:

```
$ ld -r -b binary -o template.o template.xlsx
$ objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents template.o template.o
```

I got this information from the blog post *http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/ld-blobs-2007-07-13-15-50*.

The second step is to link it into the binary, which I can do with `ld`.

How do I automate these two steps with CMake?

I have no idea at the moment how to run specific commands like the `ld` one above for the first step, and I have tried adding `files/template.o` to my target_link_libraries for the second, but `ld` just says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfiles/template.o
```

I added the following custom command to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT files/template.o
      COMMAND ld -r -b binary -o files/template.o files/template.xlsx
      COMMAND objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents files/template.o files/template.o)
```

and added files/template.o to the add_executable call.

Unfortunately, CMake says this:

> ld: cannot open output file files/template.o: No such file or directory

It is my understanding that the OUTPUT command in the `add_custom_command` allows us to tell CMake what file is being created by the COMMAND commands. So I'm a bit confused now.

I updated the CMakeLists.txt file and added a target, to make sure the template file got built:

```
add_custom_target(run ALL
    DEPENDS template.o)
```

And a dependency to make sure that it gets built before the `excelbuilder` target:

```
add_dependencies(excelbuilder run)
```

I also updated the custom command to look like this:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT template.o
      COMMAND ld -r -b binary -o template.o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/files/template.xlsx
      COMMAND objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents template.o template.o)
```

When I run this, the output is as follows (make VERBOSE=1)

```
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser -B/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
make -f src/lib/minizip/CMakeFiles/minizip_1-1.dir/build.make src/lib/minizip/CMakeFiles/minizip_1-1.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
cd /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/src/lib/minizip /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/src/lib/minizip /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/src/lib/minizip/CMakeFiles/minizip_1-1.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
make -f src/lib/minizip/CMakeFiles/minizip_1-1.dir/build.make src/lib/minizip/CMakeFiles/minizip_1-1.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `src/lib/minizip/CMakeFiles/minizip_1-1.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles  17 18 19 20 21
[ 22%] Built target minizip_1-1
make -f CMakeFiles/run.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/run.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
cd /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles/run.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles/run.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles/run.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles/run.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target run
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/run.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/run.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles 22
[ 27%] Generating template.o
ld -r -b binary -o template.o /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/files/template.xlsx
objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents template.o template.o
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles  22
[ 27%] Built target run
make -f CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
cd /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build /home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
Linking CXX executable excelbuilder
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++0x  -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -fpermissive    CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/src/common/exception.cpp.o CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/src/excelbuilder/retriever.cpp.o CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/src/excelbuilder/xlsx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/src/common/config.cpp.o CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/src/excelbuilder/main.cpp.o  -o excelbuilder -rdynamic src/lib/minizip/libminizip_1-1.so -ltinyxml2 -lmysqlcppconn -lboost_regex-mt -ltemplate.o -lz -Wl,-rpath,/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build/src/lib/minizip
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltemplate.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [excelbuilder] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/excelbuilder.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ravloony/projects/excelparser/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But file template.o has been correctly generated and is in the folder. It seems that `ld` is expecting a system library.

Comment: What have you tried? Check documentation, especially add_custom_command and add_custom_target from here http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#section_Commands

Comment: Yup I tried that, but I must be missing something because it is not running. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I'm still not getting what you do. You have template.cpp file which should be compiled first, then you combine this object file with .xlsx ? Am I correct? Error quite descriptive. Either template.cpp is not compiled before you invoke ld or you just need provide ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/files/template.o to ld command.

Comment: There is no template.cpp. There is simply a xlsx file, which I transform into an object file using the ld command. I don't want ld to find the template.o, I want it to generate it.

Comment: Could you please provide full log for command which is failed? "make VERBOSE=1" should help.

Comment: Done. Plus I added some other stuff I had managed to get working.

Comment: As you can see from log there is nothing wrong with generation, so add_custom_command works perfectly. The problem that looks like you've used template.o as target_link_library. Am I correct?

Comment: could you please provide your final target commands in cmakelists.txt?

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the end, this is how I did it.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT template.o
      COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/files && ld -r -b binary -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/template.o template.xlsx
      COMMAND objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/template.o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/template.o)
```

The `cd` commands are there because `ld` sets the names of the automatically declared variables to something depending on the full path passed to the input file. So if the input file was `/home/user/project/files/template.xlsx`, the variable would be something like `_binary_home_user_project_files_template_xlsx_start`. Not cool for portable compilation.

```
add_library(template
        STATIC
        template.o)
```

tells the linker to compile the object file into the binary. This also adds a target called `template`.

Then

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(
  template.o
  PROPERTIES
  EXTERNAL_OBJECT true
  GENERATED true
  )
```

to tell CMake not to compile the file, which is generated at build time.

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(
  template
  PROPERTIES
  LINKER_LANGUAGE C 
  )
```

Or else we get an error message, because CMake can't figure out from the ".o"-suffix that it is a C linker we need.

And then in my `target_link_libraries` step, I simply added `template` as a target.

```
target_link_libraries (excelbuilder
            ${MINIZIP_LIB_NAME}
            ${TINYXML_LIBRARIES}
            ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_LIBRARY}
            ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
            template
            )
```

Comment: Consider using `WORKING_DIRECTORY` kwarg to `add_custom_command` instead of `COMMAND cd ...`.

Comment: This is somehow not working in my project now. It says it can't find souce file and had tried extensions(all c ext)

Answer (score 1):

To link the object file into the exectuable, add it to the list of source files in `add_executable()` instead of trying to add it to `target_link_libraries()`.

For generating the object file in the first place, see [add_custom_command()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command). In this case, you will want to use its form which specifies an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work either. The object file is not linked in, so when ld does the linking of other libraries, the variables declared in the .o file are not referenced and it fails.