# ld of data file makes size of data an *ABS* and not an integer

Tags: c++, c, variables, pointers, ld

I have a c++ program which includes an external dependency on an empty xlsx file. To remove this dependency I converted this file to a binary object in view of linking it in directly, using:

```
ld -r -b binary -o template.o template.xlsx
```

followed by

```
objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents template.o template.o
```

Using objdump, I can see three variables declared :

```
$ objdump -x template.o

template.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
template.o
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000010:
HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .rodata       00000fd1  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .rodata        0000000000000000 .rodata
0000000000000fd1 g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 _binary_template_xlsx_size
0000000000000000 g       .rodata        0000000000000000 _binary_template_xlsx_start
0000000000000fd1 g       .rodata        0000000000000000 _binary_template_xlsx_end
```

I then tell my program about this data :

```
template.h:
#ifndef TEMPLATE_H
#define TEMPLATE_H

#include <cstddef>
extern "C" {
  extern const char _binary_template_xlsx_start[];
  extern const char _binary_template_xlsx_end[];
  extern const int  _binary_template_xlsx_size;
}
#endif
```

This compiles and links fine,(although I am having some trouble automating it with cmake, see here : [compile and add object file from binary with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776463/compile-and-add-object-file-from-binary-with-cmake))

However, when I use _binary_template_xlsx_size in my code, it is interpreted as a pointer to an address that doesn't exist. So to get the size of my data, I have to pass `(int)&_binary_template_xlsx_size` (or `(int)(_binary_template_xlsx_end - _binary_template_xlsx_start)`)

Some research tells me that the `*ABS*` in the objdump above means "absolute value" but I don't get why. How can I get my c++ (or c) program to see the variable as an int and not as a pointer?

Comment: I think there may be some hints in the documentation as to why or how to avoid this. Why not just write a simple script to convert the file into an includable array definition?

Comment: The file is a xlsx file: a zipped collection of xml files. The reason I did this was because I spent some time writing the code to unzip, iterate through the files, and parse the xml, and I don't want to redo all that. Plus this is fun.

Comment: Also I can access the data just fine. I'm trying to find out what is going on here, as I am intrigued by this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `*ABS*` symbol is an absolute address; it's more often created by passing `--defsym foo=0x1234` to ld.

> ```
> --defsym symbol=expression
> ```
>
> Create a global symbol in the output file, containing the  absolute
>      address given by expression.  [...]

Because an absolute symbol is a constant, it's not possible to link it into a C source file as a variable; all C object variables have an address, but a constant doesn't.

To make sure you don't dereference the address (i.e. read the variable) by accident, it's best to define it as `const char []` as you have with the other symbols:

```
  extern const char _binary_template_xlsx_size[];
```

If you want to make sure you're using it as an `int`, you could use a macro:

```
  extern const char _abs_binary_template_xlsx_size[] asm("_binary_template_xlsx_size");
  #define _binary_template_xlsx_size ((int) (intptr_t) _abs_binary_template_xlsx_size)
```