# CMake and Linking in Resource Files on Linux

Tags: linux, linker, cmake

I have two things that I want to do in a CMakeLists.txt file:

1. I want to first create an object file that is created by ld (a command like `ld -r -b binary -o binary.o foo.bar` )
2. Link in this created file into my executable

I looked into using `add_custom_target` and/or `add_custom_command`, but the CMake documentation has got me confused on how I can actually do both of these tasks effectively from within CMake.

If I add a custom target and specify my own command, how would CMake know which file to link into the executable? If I add a custom command (say PRE_LINK), how can I add it into the linking stage?

Or is there a better way to handling resource files using CMake in Linux?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** : Found that this question is essentially the same and answers my question as well: [compile and add object file from binary with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776463/compile-and-add-object-file-from-binary-with-cmake).

Answer (score 0):

CMake provides functionality to do this.

1. You can create an object from your sources using [add_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html).
2. You can then link this to your executable using [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: Sorry, but I guess I wasn't clear. The object file that I'm creating isn't an ordinary source file, but a file turned into a binary blob. I found the answer and edited my post with it.