# CMake convert text file to raw string literal

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I have a source input file

```
long content to be included
```

And want to include it and handle as a string

```
const char* mydata = 
#include "myfile.txt"
;
```

I need to make the content becomes raw string as

```
R"(long content to be included)"
```

Comment: Write `R"(` to the header file. Append the contents of the input file. Append `")`. I think CMake have functionality to do all of that built-in, you might want to read [its documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/). Otherwise you can invoke external OS-specific commands to do it (for example on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS you can use `echo` and `cat`). If you use the external solution, I recommend you create a simple script which does it all, and invoke that from CMake. Now you try, and tell us how your attempt worked or not.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. If you want the contents of arbitrary files to show up in your binary you can just do it using the linker. [Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776463/compile-and-add-an-object-file-from-a-binary-with-cmake) that uses CMake to do so.

Comment: CMake .in files are the way I've seen to do this, but I have unfortunately never setup a .in file. Hoping the search term at least helps.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use CMake's `configure_file` with the `@ONLY` option to fill in the file from a template.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Botje and John . Thanks for all your suggestions, I found a way with configure_file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions. I find a solution for my problem with `configure_file` api.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

const char *test_data = R"(
@FILE_CONTENT@
)";
int main() { printf("%s\n", test_data); }
```

```
file(READ resources/data.txt FILE_CONTENT)
configure_file(test.cpp.in test.cpp @ONLY)
```